# typescript error with VS Code. but compiles fine

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

[image: screen shot of error]

When i move my mouse over the red. it says:

Import assignment cannot be used when targeting ECMAScript 6 or higher. Consider using 'import * as ns from "mod"', 'import {a} from "mod"' or 'import d from "mod"' instead.

Like i said it compiles and runs just fine. Its just REALLY annoying having that constantly there.

I am brand new to node.js and typescript. But not brand new to programming, i'v been a C# developer for a long time.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer. I should have just done what it told me to do :)

I replaced

```
import http = require("http");
```

with

```
import * as http from "http"
```

no more complaining and it all compiles.

I followed the same pattern for the rest of the requires that I had.

Comment: Yeah these ES6 imports really are powerful. I don't write any "require"s since they are available. And I'm looking forward to use them natively.

Answer (score 0):

> Import assignment cannot be used when targeting ECMAScript 6 or higher

Open you `tsconfig.json` and add the following (replacing an existing value if already present... and merging with existing data accordingly):

```
{
    "compilerOptions" :{
        "target": "es5"
    } 
}
```